# how to send data to server asynchronously with axios without generating a response

Tags: php, axios

I am using axios to POST data to a php server.  I use the following function:

```
function sendData2(url,emailPass){

    let bodyFormData = new FormData()
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(emailPass)) {
        //console.log(key,value)
        bodyFormData.append(key,value)
    }

    return axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: bodyFormData,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
            })
                .then(function(response){
                    return response.data
                })
                .catch(function(response){
                    return response
                })
}
```

this works great but always generates a response.  Is there a way to send data asynchronously to the server and then continue from the server to render a new web page?  Does the axios.put method do that? In essence I want to cancel the response from the server or find some way of uploading data to the server that doesn't generate an axios response.

Comment: did u try await  ?

Comment: no, that misses the point.  I just want to send data to the server and not have a promise return while keeping the web page displayed